What is the difference in meaning between " a cup of coffee" and "coffee of a cup"?
What is the difference in meaning between " a cup of coffee" and "coffee of a cup" ?
Do both cases mean the same thing, or do they mean completely different things?
Does "coffee of a cup" mean "a cup made out of coffee"?

Where did you see 'coffee of a cup'?

the difference is  "coffee of a cup" isn't a valid sequence of English words in any context I can think of.

This is not something I saw, but something I was wondering about. I really don't understand the meaning of the preposition of, so I'm wondering how the meaning would change if I changed the order.

@user175012 Do you mean to say, "Would you like to have a cup of coffee?"  I don't know what is"coffee of a cup.

We can’t string together an arbitrary sequence of English words and expect that the result has any meaning. I’m quite certain that the situation is the same in your native language, whichever language that is.

In the language I use, words are created even if the order is changed. It is something that cannot be realized in reality, but it can be realized in a bizarre world through imagination. In other words, I thought that if there is a word like a cup of coffee, there can also be a word like coffee of a cup. Of course, it is a situation that cannot be imagined in reality, but I think it is possible to think about it in an imaginary world.

That is, if we can see how a sentence with its order reversed can have a bizarre alternative meaning, I think it will help us analyze how the preposition of is used in English-speaking countries.

Okay, but would you expect a string like * Table table table onion table table to have any meaning? And if not, then how is this string different from coffee of a cup?

Your premise, “we can see how a sentence with its order reversed can have a bizarre meaning,” is false, in general.  What would you have * Grandfather my is painting the in man the mean?

Are prepositions connecting words? If so, can't words be made by changing words based on prepositions? It's just that it can't be implemented in reality, so it's very strange, but if you think about a strange world, can't it make sense? Think about a world where only coffee exists. Then, if you make a cup with coffee... how should you express it?

In the past, the smallest matter was electrons or protons. Then they changed to quarks. Now they are called strings. Then, let's imagine that in the future, the fundamental matter of this world was discovered to be not strings but cups. Can you imagine a world filled with cups? Then, can't you imagine a world where coffee can be made with cups?
Isn't the idea that changing the order of words based on prepositions makes no sense based on reality? If you expand your thinking and create an imaginary world, can't you find some meaning?

What exactly is that language you use? First, cup of coffee is not a word; it's a phrase. Second, just reversing order does not work in most languages. Coffee can't be made with cups because coffee is a plant, cups are not. This reversal - Sumatran coffee or coffee of Sumatra, works, why? Because Sumatra is a place, not a thing.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on false premises about prepositions.

It would require a very contrived context.  If you were on a panel doing a taste test of some coffees, the panel might be told "We will put five cups of coffee before you, and you should take a sip of coffee of a cup, any cup you like, and proceed to do the same of the other cups, in any order that you like, jotting down the 3-character code on each cup along with your rating of the coffee in that cup. Don't discuss this with other members of the panel during the taste test."

The first phrase ("A cup of coffee") is a very common form. The second ("coffee of a cup") is not grammatical; it makes no sense at all.
The first form is used in many common phrases. In these, the word "of" means "containing":
A bowl of soup
A pitcher of beer
A bucket of paint
These phrases all refer to an object containing a substance.
Be aware that a similar form (a x of y) refers to the composition, not the contents, of an object. In these phrases, "of" means "made of":
A wall of stone (a wall made of stone)
A table of wood (a table made of wood)
In those forms, the expression can be shortened to "a (composition) (thing)" -- A stone wall, a wood table.

Let's assume that a strange world exists. If so, do " coffee of a cup" mean "coffee made of a cup" ?

@user175012 did someone, a student, a teacher, a boss or some know-it-all tell you your sentence was  wrong, and now you want to prove them wrong? A paper cup is a cup made of paper, there is no such thing as a cup made of coffee, which— possibly—might be called "a coffee cup" but that word order already has a fixed meaning, i.e. a cup for the purpose of drinking coffee. You need to say what inspired this question otherwise it will be closed. Pretty soon by the looks of it.

@user175012 Even in the universe you propose, this would be at best an unlikely and confusing utterance. It would be similar to saying something like "I had tea of a bark this afternoon", which is incredibly unidiomatic. You'd be much more likely to say "I had bark tea" in this universe, or "I had cup coffee" in the universe where you pour water over ground tableware to make a drink.

There are many constructions that can be reversed in various ways - for example, cow's milk/the milk of a cow. But "coffee of a cup" just doesn't make any sense. A cup can contain coffee, but the coffee doesn't originate with the cup in the way that milk comes from a cow. Also, a "cup of coffee" has a duality of meaning in that it also denotes the measure of coffee (a cup's worth), because when someone says they "drank a cup of coffee" they didn't ingest the cup.
"Cup of coffee" is such a common noun phrase that nobody could mistake it for a 'cup made of coffee', unless for deliberate, humourous purposes. My old English teacher used to like asking us to find unusual ambiguities in phrases - the one I always remember was "my father travels to work in a bowler hat" which could sound like the hat was his vehicle, but again, nobody would make that mistake because it isn't logical.

You might be looking for "coffee in a cup".
Prepositions designate a unique semantic relationship between two nouns. You can't just switch the arguments and expect it to still make sense: a cat on a table is different from a table on a cat just like 10/2 is different from 2/10.
There's often (even usually) a different preposition that describes the same relationship in the opposite direction, like a table under a cat or (10^-1)*2. But there's no general rule to tell you which one will do this; it's highly context dependent.
Tl;dr prepositions are not commutative!

OP has asked:

What is the difference in meaning between " a cup of coffee" and "coffee of a cup" ?

Your first phrase "a cup of coffee" is correct and can be used in this manner:
Would you like to have a cup of coffee?
Since you have asked about prepositions (in the comments), I decided to answer your question.
The phrase "coffee of a cup" is not possible - instead prepositions  "off and from" can be used.
He poured coffee off (from) the cup.
Edit-1.
Referring to the comment:.

Can you imagine a world filled with cups? Then, can't you imagine a world where coffee can be made with cups? Isn't the idea that changing the order of words based on prepositions makes no sense based on reality? If you expand your thinking and create an imaginary world, can't you find some meaning?

You have created a science fiction/ or Alice in Wonderland type of story - coffee can be made with cups.
Let's distinguish between imagination and everyday communication.
Imagination is limitless, but language needs clarity. In reality, coffee comes from beans, not cups.
